# Getting hyperlinks, bookmarks, and TOC all right

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, appendices, bookmarks

I'm having trouble getting all three of the hyperlinks, PDF bookmarks, and the TOC "right". The following gives me the correct visual styling: Appendices appears in the TOC as a "part", before the actual appendix chapters. The hyperlink points to the wrong page, though (it's one or two pages too soon), and the PDF bookmarks for the Appendices are all placed inside the last chapter before the appendices.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{One}
\chapter{One}

%\addappheadtotoc
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendices}
\part*{Appendices}
%\currentpdfbookmark{Appendices}{Appendices}
\phantomsection
\appendix

\chapter{First}

\end{document}
```

I tried several combinations and orders of the above, to no avail. Uncommenting the `\currentpdfbookmark` line gives me a double "Appendices" bookmark, one without any levels, and another one as it should be (the latter links to the page of the first appendix, which is not really optimal but I can live with it).

Any help is greatly appreciated. Or an alternative way to keep a "part-level" Appendix entry with the above requirements would be nice as well.

Comment: `\addcontentsline` will always add the bookmark automatically unless redefined

Comment: add a `\clearpage` before you want to start you appendix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be avoided using the environment `appendices` instead of `\appendix`.

Load the `appendix` package with the options `toc` and `page`

```
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
```

to have the ToC entry and the page with "Appendix".

Also redefine `\addappheadtotoc` if you want a part to be added to the ToC instead of a chapter.

```
\renewcommand{\addappheadtotoc}{%
  \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\appendixtocname}%
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\addappheadtotoc}{%
  \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\appendixtocname}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{One}
\chapter{One}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{First}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

and the bookmarks

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this gets everything right as far as I can tell.

Comment: @rubenvb Glad to help.